# Ansible\AWX - Powershell JSON-Object not returning my items

Tags: ansible

Still working on my first playbook. I'm running into a problem when i try to access a JSON object.

I have a little script that checks for 2 groups to exist or not:

```
- name: Verify if the groups already exists in AD
  register: lookupResult
  win_shell: |
  $groups = @()
  Try{
      $group = Get-ADGroup {{ GroupNameUpper }}  | Select Name, DistinguishedName
      $groups += [PSCustomObject]@{
          Name              = $group.Name
          DistinguishedName = $group.DistinguishedName
          Message           = "Group already exists"
      }
  }  catch  {
      $groups += [PSCustomObject]@{
          Name              =  "{{ GroupNameUpper }}"
          DistinguishedName = ""
          Message           = "Does not exist"
      }
  }  Try  {
      $group = Get-ADGroup  "{{ GroupNameUpper }}_GrpMgmt"  | Select Name, DistinguishedName
      $groups += [PSCustomObject]@{
          Name              = $group.Name
          DistinguishedName = $group.DistinguishedName
          Message           = "Group already exists"
      }
  }  catch  {
      $groups += [PSCustomObject]@{
          Name              =  "{{ GroupNameUpper }}_GrpMgmt"
          DistinguishedName = ""
          Message           = "Does not exist"
      }      
  }
  $Json = $groups | convertTo-Json
  $Json
```

When i display the output, it looks like nicely formed JSON

```
- name: Show output
 debug:
 msg: "{{ lookupResult.stdout_lines|list }}"
```

It looks like so:

```
TASK [Show output] *************************************************************
ok: [server] => {
    "msg": [
        "[",
        "    {",
        "        \"Name\":  \"R_UC_APP_Testapp\",",
        "        \"DistinguishedName\":  \"\",",
        "        \"Message\":  \"Does not exist\"",
        "    },",
        "    {",
        "        \"Name\":  \"R_UC_APP_Testapp_GrpMgmt\",",
        "        \"DistinguishedName\":  \"CN=R_UC_APP_testapp_GrpMgmt,whatever,DC=com\",",
        "        \"Message\":  \"Group already exists\"",
        "    }",
        "]"
    ]
}
```

In the UI, i can look at the JSON with the next task and it shows up fine there too:

```
- name: Process win_shell output
 set_fact:
 testOutput: "{{ lookupResult.stdout | from_json  }}"
```

According to this page i should be able to access my object `testoutput` https://www.jonathanmedd.net/2019/07/returning-data-from-powershell-scripts-to-be-consumed-by-ansible-playbooks.html

```
- name: Inform that group already exists
  debug:
     msg: "Group {{ testOutput.Name }} ."
when: "'already exists' in lookupResult.stdout"
```

But it doesn't work and returns the error
`"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'Name'`

The only difference between my code and the example-code on the website, is the fact that my JSON-object has 2. But that shouldn't be an issue right?

I have tried many different things but i've come to a stall. Anyone can help me out please?

Thanks so much in advance!

**EDIT:**
So i'm a bit closer thanks to the loop suggestion. However, this prints too much information. I just want to see the msg.

```
  - name: Debug Loop
    debug: 
     msg: "Group : {{ item.Name }} , {{ item.Message }} in domain {{ domainName }}"
    loop: "{{ testOutput }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out you have two elements in your list, so what you'd need to do is to iterate through each element, you can do that using the loop or with keywords. There are some examples in the below link but in real terms it's like asking a room of two people, what there name is and only being able to write down one of them.

: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

Comment: Got a bit closer with the loop. However, it shows me too much detail. I just need\want to show the message i created .

Answer (score 0):

i dunno if your testOutput.stdout is directly a json format:

```
  - name: Debug Loop
    debug: 
      msg: "Group : {{ item.Name }} , {{ item.Message }} in domain {{ domainName }}"
    loop: "{{ testOutput.stdout }}"
```

if its a string do a `loop: "{{ testOutput.stdout | from_json }}"`

for more precision show the content of testOutput.stdout

---

```
- name: Inform that group already exists
  debug:
    msg: "Group {{ item.Name }} ."
  loop: "{{ testOutput.stdout | from_json }}"   
  when: "'already exists' in item.Message"
```

Comment: Thank you Frenchy for your help.
I've tried this and i also tried it with `stdout_lines` but i always receive the following error:
`"Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({{ testOutput.stdout_lines | from_json }}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'AnsibleUndefined'"`

Comment: why are you using stdout_lines ? use stdout... stdout_lines is a list of each lines, its no good to use as json

Comment: Sorry i didn't communicate clearly, my bad. What i meant to say was:
I tried `stdout` but because that didn't work i also tried `stdout_lines`.

Comment: could you debug your variable lookupResult  (show  complete content)..i think the problem is in the format of your register variable.. do a debug: msg: "{{lookupResult}}"  if its too big just show "{{lookupResult.stdout}}"

Comment: Since it is way to long to paste here, i've made a gist : https://gist.github.com/KristofStroobants/3489001a10e74929c72ccef40b5f4e6f

Comment: sorry i dont understant why you have a key ansible_facts, could you debug {lookupResult.stdout}} instead the result of set_fact

Comment: Sorry for the late reply and thank you for your contenious help.
Sadly I am unexpectedly on call. So i will get back to you once things cool down. Just wanted to let you know i did not "ghost you".